# Converting from UTC to US Mountain time with DST

Tags: c#, timezone

I have been searching around for how to convert from UTC to mountain time and I have successfully found the following function that everyone says takes into account DST. Whenever it converts from UTC to Mountain it's always -7 for the offset (when it should be -6 currently). Except it doesn't seem to be. Can anyone shine some light on this for me or a way to make it take into account DST?

```
DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(createdDate.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime mountainTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcTime, "US Mountain Standard Time");
```

Thanks,
Dman

Comment: Is you goal to specifically convert UTC to Mountain or is it to convert UTC to the client's timezone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like there are two zones in .NET (at least on my Windows 8 installation) which are mountain time.

There's "US Mountain Standard Time" which you're using, and which doesn't observe DST (it's for Arizona) - and plain "Mountain Standard Time" which *does* observe DST. So you just need to get rid of the "US " part and it will work:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime octoberUtc = new DateTime(2012, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime decemberUtc = new DateTime(2012, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        ConvertToMountainTime(octoberUtc);
        ConvertToMountainTime(decemberUtc);
    }

    static void ConvertToMountainTime(DateTime utc)
    {
        DateTime mountain = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId
            (utc, "Mountain Standard Time");

        Console.WriteLine("{0} (UTC) = {1} Mountain time", utc, mountain);
    }
}
```

Output (UK culture):

```
01/10/2012 00:00:00 (UTC) = 30/09/2012 18:00:00 Mountain time
01/12/2012 00:00:00 (UTC) = 30/11/2012 17:00:00 Mountain time
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everytime I see an answer from you Jon it's usually bang on! Great work and keep up your contributions to SO!

Comment: The "US Mountain Standard Time" zone is for Arizona, which does not implement daylight savings.  Check the DisplayName property, and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Mountain Standard Time is still -7. Contray to popular belief, we don't change our time, but our time **zone**. Our current time zone is actually Mountain Daylight Time. Figuring out time zone information is.... unpleasant

Comment: Unfortunately it's worse than that - because the time zone ID .NET uses *is* typically the standard time ID, for the whole time zone. (And no, you don't change your time zone. One time zone covers the whole of time, and it knows about DST changes.) So for example, in the more standard zoneinfo/tzdb time zone database, I use the "Europe/London" time zone, which alternates between UTC and UTC+1.

Comment: I think he means that the region changes between MST and MDT (both distinct time zones), and not that a programmer needs to change between time zones for that locale.